# Policy Exception: Server Policy Rejection (Code 7)

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a custom BackupAgent for my app. I am invoking the agent from adb shell.
on calling backup, i can see all the debug logs till the end of the method, but then it throws this error:

```
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674): Server policy rejection: 
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674): com.google.android.backup.BackupRequestGenerator$PolicyException: server error in app <app package>: code 7
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674):     at com.google.android.backup.BackupRequestGenerator.parseResponse(BackupRequestGenerator.java:360)
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674):     at com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService.sendRequestLocked(BackupTransportService.java:849)
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674):     at com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService.access$600(BackupTransportService.java:78)
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674):     at com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService$1.finishBackup(BackupTransportService.java:444)
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674):     at com.android.server.BackupManagerService$PerformBackupTask.operationComplete(BackupManagerService.java:2320)
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674):     at com.android.server.BackupManagerService$BackupHandler.handleMessage(BackupManagerService.java:572)
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 21:01:52.839: E/BackupTransportService(1674):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

---

also on calling restore (again from adb shell), no debug logs are ever printed.
Any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your Android Backup Service key in your manifest.  I just solved this problem myself by re-registering for a new key. My package name in my manifest has some capital letters and I think I kept it all lower case the first time I registered. I registered again with a direct copy-paste of the package name from my manifest and now it works.